# Abdera SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, ibm-connections, apache-abdera

I have a litte problem with the SSL Handshake, with I try to launch a GET request, the server return me  java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException.

I'm using Abdera for the connection with the Connections Server, and on Websphare I did install the SSL of the Connections Site, but this din't work, my code it's:

public static void send(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse respo) throws Exception {

```
    String back = "";

    String connectionsUser = req.getHeader("user");
    String connectionsPassword = req.getHeader("password");

    Abdera abdera = new Abdera();
    AbderaClient abderaClient = new AbderaClient(abdera);

    AbderaClient.registerTrustManager();

    System.out.println(connectionsUser + "    " + connectionsPassword);
    abderaClient.addCredentials(Utils.configJson.getString("connectionsServer"), null, null, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(connectionsUser, connectionsPassword));

    ClientResponse resp = abderaClient.get(Utils.configJson.getString("connectionsServerURL") + Utils.configJson.getString("profileService"));
```

and the log it's:

```
[8/27/15 17:14:56:663 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.execute(AbderaClient.java:701)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.get(AbderaClient.java:216)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.get(AbderaClient.java:404)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.cemex.services.ProfileServiceDo.send(ProfileServiceDo.java:71)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.cemex.services.ProfileServiceDo.doGet(ProfileServiceDo.java:38)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:664 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3774)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:665 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
[8/27/15 17:14:56:666 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:36)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:43)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.b(SSLSocketImpl.java:32)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:626)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:39)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:696)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.k.write(k.java:26)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:134)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:827)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1525)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1975)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:668 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:669 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:669 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:669 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:669 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     at org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.execute(AbderaClient.java:688)
[8/27/15 17:14:56:669 CDT] 0000007c SystemErr     R     ... 30 more
```

you have idea that happen with the SSL or how resolve?

thaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the Connections Server into the CellDefaultTrustSTore if you are running the application on a WebSphere Application Server.

You can refer to security certificates to https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_5.0.0/admin/install/t_exchange_keys_network.dita

```
Log into the IBM WebSphere Application Server Integrated Solutions Console and select Security > SSL Certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates.
Click CellDefaultTrustStore.
Click Signer Certificates.
Click Retrieve from port.
Enter the Host name, SSL Port, and Alias of the web server. The Alias is typically an arbitrary string that will become the name of the credentials.
Click Retrieve Signer Information and then click OK. The root certificate is added to the list of signer certificates.
```

You have to sync the node afterwards

Comment: yes I do this but not work, I added the certificate to Websphere but the SSLhandshake Exceptions continue.

Comment: You'll have to restart the node. .... are you running Aberra standalone or as part of the AppServer? if standalone, you'll have to import the certificate into the TrustStore of the JVM

Comment: alternatively refer to this topic https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ABDERA/AtomPub+Client Using SSL

Comment: thanks the problem was solve, with only comments because, I use the documentation, and added the certificate to Websphere, and comment the line of  AbderaClient.registerTrustManager(); and the service work.